# How do I label a stacked bar chart in ggplot2 without creating a summary data frame?

Tags: r, label, ggplot2, bar-chart

The following code provides a wonderful stacked bar chart

```
cls.grp <- gl(n=4,k=20,labels=c("group a","group b","group c", "group d"))
ser <- sample(x=c("neg","pos"),size=80,replace=TRUE, prob=c(30,70))
syrclia <- data.frame(cls.grp,ser)
ggplot(syrclia, aes(cls.grp, fill=ser))+ geom_bar()
```

I was expecting that with geom_text or stat_summary I would be able to label the percentage who were negative in each group and put it on the corresponding bar. I have tried many permutations and cannot get it to work. I have even tried manually entering the percentages and forcing the labels where I want them but it does not work. It expects 80 labels and I only want to give four that are negative or perhaps 8 (if one includes the labels for the percentage that are positive).

Do I really have to make an aggregated data frame of my syrclia and plot that?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of what labels you'd like to place on the bars with a description of what labels you expect to go where?

Answer (score 7):

`geom_bar` uses `stat_bin` by default. So you should use `stat_bin` to plot the numbers, tell it to use `geom_text` and use the newly produced `..count..` as label.

```
    cls.grp <- gl(n=4,k=20,labels=c("group a","group b","group c", "group d"))
    ser <- sample(x=c("neg","pos"),size=80,replace=TRUE, prob=c(30,70))
    syrclia <- data.frame(cls.grp,ser)
    library(ggplot2)
    total <- ddply(syrclia, .(cls.grp), function(x) nrow(x))[, 2]
    ggplot(syrclia, aes(cls.grp, fill=ser))+ geom_bar() + 
      stat_bin(geom = "text", 
               aes(label = paste(
                   ..count../get("total", envir = .GlobalEnv)*100,"%")))
```

HTH
[image]

Comment: I have a little complication. In my real data set there are not 20 per column. They are a variable number. I need the count to calculate the count per column and to add a "%" sign.